# listview audio play with custom path

Tags: android, listview, audio-player, android-music-player

this is music player cursor; it's works good and its show all songs from sdcard to listview but i want particular folder only, how to add custom folder path at query?

musicAdapter = new RecordPlayerAdapter(this);

```
    Cursor musicCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            musicAdapter.add(new RecordPlayerBridge(
                    musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)),
                    musicCursor.getLong(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)),
                    musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
            ));
        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add the desired folder as query parameter

**Code:**

```
Cursor musicCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, 
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
                //Here in the query you add the desired folder for example iron_maiden folder.
                new String[] {"%iron_maiden%"},
                null);
```

I hope it solve your problem.